# PHP - warning - Undefined property: stdClass - fix?

Tags: php, object, warnings

I get this warning in my error logs and wanted to know how to correct this issues in my code.

Warning:
PHP Notice:  Undefined property:  stdClass::$records in script.php on line 440

Some Code:

```
// Parse object to get account id's
// The response doesn't have the records attribute sometimes.
$role_arr = getRole($response->records);  // Line 440
```

Response if records exists

```
stdClass Object
(
    [done] => 1
    [queryLocator] =>
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => User
                    [Id] =>
                    [any] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => My Role
                            [Id] =>
                            [any] => <sf:Name>My Name</sf:Name>
                        )

                )

        )

    [size] => 1
)
```

Response if records does not exist

```
stdClass Object
(
    [done] => 1
    [queryLocator] =>
    [size] => 0
)
```

I was thinking something like array_key_exists() functionality but for objects, anything? or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: To explain, I've intentionally close this page with a more recent page.  Though counter-intuitive on the surface, it is the recommended behavior on Stack Overflow to give greater priority to pages with better content versus trying to simply preserve the oldest page.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

```
if(isset($response->records))
    print "we've got records!";
```

Comment: can "or" be used somehow? example: $foo = $bar->foo or "default";

Comment: How can I use this solution in a foreach? Example: `foreach($product->images as $images)` ?

Answer (score 8):

In this case, I would use:

```
if (!empty($response->records)) {
 // do something
}
```

You won't get any ugly notices if the property doesn't exist, and you'll know you've actually got some records to work with, ie. $response->records is not an empty array, NULL, FALSE, or any other empty values.

Answer (score 8):

isset() is fine for top level, but empty() is much more useful to find whether nested values are set. Eg:

```
if(isset($json['foo'] && isset($json['foo']['bar'])) {
    $value = $json['foo']['bar']
}
```

Or:

```
if (!empty($json['foo']['bar']) {
    $value = $json['foo']['bar']
}
```

Comment: `if(isset($json['foo'] && isset($json['foo']['bar'])) {` is performing a needless check.  Besides the fact that `isset()` could happily receive both of the variables in a single call, just check for the deeper element that you intend to access.  `if(isset($json['foo']['bar'])) {`

Comment: @mickmackusa - yeah. No idea why I had that opinion 6 years ago, but it is what it is. I don't think isset() changed behaviour from 5.X to current, but either way, what you say is correct.

Comment: @markdwhite I thought it worked the same as you tbh. Turns out it was changed in 5.4 to work the same. I guess we're old ;)

Comment: I agree that checking both is a needless case, but is you ever need to, you can use only one isset -> `isset($json['foo'], $json['bar'])`

Answer (score 5):

You can use property_exists
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `property_exists`, you'll need to get the name of the class with `get_class()`

In this case it would be :

```
 if( property_exists( get_class($response), 'records' ) ){
       $role_arr = getRole($response->records);
 }
 else
 {
       ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Null Coalesce Operator**

You can use the [isset_ternary](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) operator `??`. This allows you to avoid warnings and assign default value in a short one line fashion.

```
$role_arr = getRole($response->records ?? null);
```

---

**Error control operator**

In case the warning is expected you can use the [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` to suppress thrown messages.

```
$role_arr = getRole(@$response->records);
```

While this reduces clutter in your code you should use it with caution as it may make debugging future errors harder. An example where using `@` may be useful is when creating an object from user input and running it through a validation method before using it in further logic.

Comment: 1. I would never recommend the "stfu operator" (`@`) -- I never use it in my code because it indicates that a developer is lazily choosing not to properly handle a problem.  2. If `getRole()` expects to receive an iterable type value, then passing `null` is a bad idea -- without a deeper understanding of the application, it's probably wiser to fallback to `[]` (an empty array).  That said, I definitely do support the recommendation of using the "null coalescing operator" (`??`).

Answer (score 1):

The response itself seems to have the size of the records. You can use that to check if records exist. Something like:

```
if($response->size > 0){
    $role_arr = getRole($response->records);
}
```

Comment: This is the lightest / most direct approach if you only want to declare `$role_arr` if there are records to process.  The `$response` object appears to unconditionally offer the `size` property, so use that and more on.  Note that the same effect is achieved with `if ($response->size) {` since `0` is a falsey value.

Answer (score 0):

If think this will work:

```
if(sizeof($response->records)>0)
$role_arr = getRole($response->records);
```

newly defined proprties included too.